# cancel element drag by attribute

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to disable some elements from draging by their attribute. I do

```
$( ".main_table tbody" ).sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        var level = ui.item.attr('level')
        $( ".main_table tbody" ).sortable("option", "cancel", '[level!='+level+']');
    }
});
```

But it: 1. applies `cancel` after `stop`; 2. applies `cancel` to all element. http://fiddle.jshell.net/vQL8h/ So I need to disable drag on 8,9 when drag 1st or 2nd row

Comment: Can you post your HTML or a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vQL8h/